# How do I flip Player in 2D Touch Movement?

Tags: 2d, movement, unity

How do i flip my Player in 2D when i got touch movement? 
I got Buttons to move but how do I flip the player now if i walk to the right cause my player faces to the left..?

here is my Player Script:

```
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10, jumpVelocity =  10;
    public LayerMask playerMask;
    public bool canMoveInAir = true;
    Transform myTrans, tagGround;
    Rigidbody2D myBody;
    bool isGrounded = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myTrans = this.transform;   
        tagGround = GameObject.Find (this.name + "/tag_ground").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (myTrans.position, tagGround.position, playerMask);

        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_BLACKBERRY && !UNITY_WINRT
        Move(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));   
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
           Jump();
        #endif
    }

    public void Move(float horizontalInput) 
    {
        //Er klebt nicht mehr an den Waenden
        if (!canMoveInAir && !isGrounded)
            return;

        Vector2 moveVel = myBody.velocity;
        moveVel.x = horizontalInput * speed;
        myBody.velocity = moveVel;  


    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if(isGrounded)
            myBody.velocity += jumpVelocity * Vector2.up;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flipping object through can be done through scaling. If you set scale to -1 in X then it'd be flipped in X axis, similar for other axes.

You can just use your `horizontalInput` to determine if you are going left or right, and obviously if your `horizontalInput` is negative then your going left and vice versa.

```
public void Move(float horizontalInput) 
{
    ...
    // Here is the flipping stuff
    if (horizontalInput != 0)
    {
        Vector3 flip = Vector3.right * horizontalInput * myTrans.localScale.x;
        myTrans.localScale = flip;
    }
}
```

As you taking `horizontalInput` with `Input.GetAxisRaw` means with no smoothing filter so I did multiply it directly, but if you change it whenever then you have to make some change in code also, what you have to do is just change

```
Vector3 flip = Vector3.right * horizontalInput * myTrans.localScale.x;
```

### To

```
Vector3 flip = (Vector3.right * horizontalInput).normalized * myTrans.localScale.x;
```

Comment: i added the Code but now it resizes my character to 0 and it fall trough the ground, my player Scale is 25x and 25y what should i do now ?

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: You should not hard code like that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;`

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer: as Valryon said, this is not the right way to do that anymore.**

Your Question is not clear, but I think what you want to do is flip the entire GameObject.
To do this, simply do `myTrans.localScale *= -1` when the player changes direction.

You can also do something like this:

```
if(horizontalInput <  0)
    myTrans.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1, 1)
if(horizontalInput >  0)
    myTrans.localScale = new Vector2(-1, -1, -1)
```

at the end of the Move(float horizontalInput) function.

Comment: I just get an Error if i try ur Code..

and yes i wanna change the direction of the GameObject

Comment: okey i got it u just used this Code:

  if (horizontalInput < 0) 
  {
   transform.localScale = new Vector2 (25, 25);
  }
  if (horizontalInput > 0) 
  {
   transform.localScale = new Vector2 (-25, 25);
  }

Comment: Yes, of course you need to adjust the values to the scale you want your GameObject to be.

Comment: I was also using this technique, but I discovered that using scale to flip is discouraged since Unity 5.4 (it logs a warning on the colliders). The appropriate way is now the flipX boolean on the SpriteRenderer.